# How can i share page title in every html page

Tags: html, github-pages

I have multiple html pages in which index.html calls all other html pages.
Index.html contains the Head with Title tag, is there any way I can share the same Head with Title tag across all other html pages?

I am hosting the html pages in github as [skpatro.github.io/demo](http://skpatro.github.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GitHub Pages then you can use [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/).

You might be able to do this using a layout that contains stuff like the title. Or you could store the title in a site-wide variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a templating engine, like [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/). With it, you can make a base HTML which contains the same title or anything that's shared between your web pages. I've used Nunjucks with Grunt before, not hard to set up. It produces static web pages so you can still use Github Pages after.